# Why is my "print" function only read the last element and garbage then stop responding?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NULL 0

struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float marks;
    struct student *next
};
typedef struct student node;
void main()
{
    node *head;
    void read(node *p);
    void create(node *p);
    int count(node *p);
    void print(node *p);
    head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    read(head);
    printf("\n");
    print(head);
}
void read(node *list)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[30];
    printf("input file name: ");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        return; // file doesn't exist
    }
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f", list->name, &list->id, &list->marks) == 3)
    {
        printf("%s \t%d \t%f\n", list->name,list->id,list->marks);//check
        list->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));//create next node
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
void print(node*list)
{
    if(list->next!=NULL)
       {
           printf("ID=%d\n",list->id);
           printf("Name=%s\n",list->name);
           printf("Marks=%f\n",list->marks);
           printf("\n");
           if(list->next->next==NULL)
            {
                printf("%d",list->next->id);
            }
           print(list->next);
       }
       return;
}
```

It looks like it printed the last line and next line(which is garbage).I think the problem is in the read function ? Since I dont feel the way I check it is accurate.
Anyway i have not been able to fix this, so it will be very helpful if someone can teach me where is the fault and better way to fix it.

output:

```
input file name: input.txt.txt
student01       1       95.000000
student03       3       90.000000
student05       5       86.000000
student07       7       83.000000
student09       9       98.000000
student10       10      93.000000
student08       8       92.000000
student06       6       96.000000
student04       4       93.000000
student02       2       88.000000

ID=2
Name=student02
Marks=88.000000

ID=11552328
░ame=P
Marks=13640062821560266000000000000000000.000000


Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 6.737 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: regarding: `#define NULL 0`   This is not a valid definition of NULL.   A valid definition would be `#define NULL void *0`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   it is missing the prototype for `printf()` and `fopen()` and `scanf()` and `fscanf()`  and NULL   and `FILE`  and `fclose()` all of this could have been corrected by including the header file: `stdio.h`

Comment: regarding the statement: `void main()`   There are only two valid signatures for `main()`   they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: the function name `read()` is a well known function.  It is a poor programming practice to try to replace the definitions of C library functions with a 'home grown' function

Comment: in the definition of the `struct student`, this field: `struct student *next`  is not valid because it is missing the required trailing semicolor `;`

Comment: regarding these statements/prototypes:  `void read(node *p);
    void create(node *p);
    int count(node *p);
    void print(node *p);`   The scope of these prototypes is the function: `main()` they are not seen when working with the actual function signatures.  So the compiler will 'assume' that the  parameter types are all 'int`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",filename);`  1) When using the 'input format specifiers' `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because these specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.   2)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Those functions always return the number of successful input conversions.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%29s",filename) != 1) { //handle error }`

Comment: regarding: `if(fp == NULL)
    {
        return; // file doesn't exist
    }`  You should always inform the user of such a problem.  When the error is from a C library function, you should also display the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  All this output should be to `stderr`.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.

Comment: regarding: ``head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "malloc failed" );` followed by cleaning up and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE ):`

Comment: in function: `read()` the code fails to set the  `next` field in the just `malloc()`d struct  to NULL.  This is probably the root of your current problem

Comment: You may take some inspiration from [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like it printed the last line and next line(which is garbage).I think the problem is in the read function?

This is correct.

And here is why:

```
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f", list->name, &list->id, &list->marks) == 3)
    {
        printf("%s \t%d \t%f\n", list->name,list->id,list->marks);//check
        list->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));//create next node
    }
```

In this loop you always read all the data in the first element of your list.
You allocate some new node but you never assign anything to it. 
You even do not terminate the list by assigning `NULL` to `list->next->next`.

This causes various problems:

- You allocate memory for each iteration but only the last one is accessible via `list->next`. All other memory blocks are lost.
- You have an unterminated list which causes undefined behaviour when you try to iterate over all nodes during printing.
- You read all data into 1 location meaning you've lost all but the last line from your file.

To fix this you need to change it like this:

```
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f", list->name, &list->id, &list->marks) == 3)
    {
        printf("%s \t%d \t%f\n", list->name,list->id,list->marks);//check
        list->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));//create next node
        if (list->next != NULL)
        {
            list = list->next; // Advance to new node
            list->next = NULL; // Terminate list at this node (until a new one is added)
        }
        else
        {
          // error handling
          exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Besides that:

- You are obviously not using an embedded system where `main` might have `void` return type. For all hosted environments it has to return `int`.
- Why do you define standard macro `NULL`? You should included the C standard header that defined it. Besides that `NULL`is a pointer value. Why do you use integer type?

Comment: Can you explain more by  I'm not assigning my data to the node?

Comment: You allocate a pointer `list->next` but never assign any value to any field of the allocated memory. I am not sure what might be unclear here...

Comment: Or put it this way: where do you think, you use that new node?

Comment: Sorry im really new at this. I assume you meant that I always read the file and assign it at the first node instead going to the next one ?

Comment: Yes, correct. You do not switch to the new/next node.

Comment: This will sound very silly but how do i do that ? I though list->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); supposed to move the node to next one after making it ?

Answer (score 1):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs most error checking
3. actually produce a linked list of `struct student`
4. documents why each header file is included
5. eliminates most of the 'magic' numbers
6. initializes the `next` field properly
7. fails to pass the allocated memory areas to `free()`
8. properly passes the address of `head` to the `read()` function so when the list is empty, the contents of `head` can be updated with the pointer to the first `node`
9. properly initializes the `head` pointer to NULL
10. properly links each new node to the prior node

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // FILE, fopen, fclose, scanf(), fscanf(), printf()
#include <stdio.h>    // malloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>   // memcpy()

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 20
#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 30

struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];
    float marks;
    struct student *next;
};
typedef struct student node;


void read_echo_records  (node **p);
void create(node *p);
int  count (node *p);
void print (node *p);


int main( void )
{
    node *head = NULL;

    read_echo_records( &head);
    printf("\n");
    print(head);
}


void read_echo_records(node **list)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[ MAX_FILENAME_LEN ];
    printf("input file name: ");
    scanf("%29s",filename);

    fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    node *current = *list;
    node *prior   = *list;
    node workspace;
    workspace.next = NULL;

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %f", workspace.name, &workspace.id, &workspace.marks) == 3)
    {
        printf("%s \t%d \t%f\n", workspace.name, workspace.id, workspace.marks);//check

        if( ! (current = malloc(sizeof(node))) )//create next node
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        memcpy( current, &workspace, sizeof( node ) );
        *prior->next = current;
        prior = current;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}


void print(node*list)
{
    node *current = list;
    if( ! current )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", "list is empty" );
        return;
    }

    while( current->next )
    {
       printf( "ID=%d\n", current->id );
       printf( "Name=%s\n", current->name );
       printf( "Marks=%f\n", current->marks );
       printf( "\n");
       current = current->next;
    } 
}
```